# Simplify $\frac{3}2\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{2+\pi^2}}\right)+\frac{1}4 \sin^{-1} (\frac{2 \sqrt 2 \pi}{2+\pi^2}) +\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt 2}\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have to simplify

$$\frac{3}{2}\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{2+{\pi}^2}}\right)+\frac{1}{4} \sin^{-1} \left(\frac{2 \sqrt 2 \pi}{2+{\pi}^2}\right) +\tan^{-1}{\frac{\sqrt2}{\pi}}$$

My attempt:-
Let $\sqrt{\frac{2}{2+{\pi}^2}} =\cos{\theta}$

so that implies: $\sin{\theta}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2+{\pi^2}}}$

similarly $\tan{\theta}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$

so the original expression simplifies to
$$\frac{3}{2} {\theta}+\frac{\theta}{2}+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-{\theta}\right)$$

Which is $$ \theta +\frac{\pi}{2}$$

which gives $$\frac{\pi}{2} +\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2+{\pi^2}}}\right)$$

however, the answer is supposed to be an integer, which this is clearly not.

Where am I going wrong?

Source:- JEE Advanced 2022, paper 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to this term $\sin^{-1} \left(\frac{2 \sqrt 2 \pi}{2+{\pi}^2}\right)$. Since the angle: $\frac{\pi}4<\theta<\frac{\pi}2$, so we have $\frac{\pi}2<2\theta<\pi$. But for inverse sine, its range is $\left[-\frac{\pi}2, \frac{\pi}2\right]$. Therefore,

$$\sin^{-1} \left(\frac{2 \sqrt 2 \pi}{2+{\pi}^2}\right)=\pi-2\theta$$

Comment: Thanks, But that still makes the answer $\theta +\pi$, which isn't an integer, so is there no way to simplify the answer further?

Comment: No, the $\theta$ is canceled out. @mathandphysicsforever

Comment: ah, got it. Thanks!

Comment: So does it match your answer in that paper? @mathandphysicsforever

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one thing, I'm not sure I understand why $\theta$ lies between $0.25 \pi and 0.5 \pi$, mind explaining that, please

Comment: Because your $\tan \theta=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2} >1$, this means $\theta>\frac{\pi}4$ @mathandphysicsforever

Comment: Ah, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Better to assume

$\displaystyle \tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\bigg)=\alpha\Longrightarrow \tan(\alpha)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}$,

Where $\displaystyle \alpha\in\bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\bigg)$

Then using Right angle Triangle , we get

$\displaystyle \sin(\alpha)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2+\pi^2}}$ and $\displaystyle \cos(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2+\pi^2}}$

Then expression convert into

$\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}\cos^{-1}(\sin(\alpha))+\frac{1}{4}\bigg(2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)\bigg)+\alpha$

$\displaystyle =\frac{3}{2}\cos^{-1}\bigg(\cos\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\bigg)\bigg)+\frac{1}{4}\sin^{-1}\bigg(\sin(2\alpha)\bigg)+\alpha$

$\displaystyle =\frac{3}{2}\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\bigg)+\frac{1}{4}\bigg(2\alpha\bigg)+\alpha=\frac{3\pi}{4}$